# akka-http implicit json format for list of case classes

Tags: json, scala, marshalling, implicit, akka-http

i want ro make a response

```
val res: List[Categories] = CategoryObj.getCategories
complete(OK, res)
```

i wrote an implicit json formats

```
implicit val jsCat = jsonFormat3(Category)
implicit val jsCats = jsonFormat1(Seq[Category])
```

but for a second line i got three errors

> Error:(8, 25) inferred type arguments
> [Seq[DAO.Category],Seq[DAO.Category]] do not conform to method
> jsonFormat1's type parameter bounds [P1,T <: Product]   implicit val
> jsCats = jsonFormat1(Seq[Category])
>
> Error:(8, 40) type mismatch;  found   : Seq[DAO.Category] =>
> Seq[DAO.Category]  required: P1 => T  Note: implicit value jsCats is
> not applicable here because it comes after the application point and
> it lacks an explicit result type   implicit val jsCats =
> jsonFormat1(Seq[Category])
>
> Error:(8, 36) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
> type spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol.JF[P1] (Cannot find JsonWriter or
> JsonFormat type class for P1)   implicit val jsCats =
> jsonFormat1(Seq[Category])

And i can't get how to deal with them

Comment: Is your Category class a case class?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44, case class, as i mentioned in title

Comment: if you comment the Seq[Category] it should work. Does it give errors of missing serializer if you comment that line?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44, yes, it threw an error but i already got a right code and gave an answer

Answer (score 2):

`Seq[Category]` is obviously not a subtype of `Product`

```
inferred type arguments [Seq[DAO.Category],Seq[DAO.Category]] do not conform to method jsonFormat1's type parameter bounds [P1,T <: Product]
```

while case classes are subtypes of `Product`.

At https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-http-quickstart-scala/json.html it's written

```
implicit val usersJsonFormat = jsonFormat1(Users) 

final case class Users(users: immutable.Seq[User])
```

i.e. `jsonFormat1` is applied to a case class wrapping a `Seq`, not to `Seq` itself.

Comment: Yes, `implicit val jsCat = jsonFormat3(Category)` was enough but with some changes which i mentioned in my own answer below. Anyway thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem was i had just simple object for application.

```
object myApp {
  // my code
}
```

These changes helped

```
trait appJSONProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val jsCat = jsonFormat3(Category)
}

object myApp extends App with appJSONProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  // my code ...
}
```